# Is Miss rate for L2 cache taken as ratio of L2 misses to Total no of instructions referred OR Total no of instructions missed by L1 cache?

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

```
During a program execution, out of 1000 memory references there are 250 and 
120 misses in L1 (Level-1) and L2(Level-2)
caches respectively. Hit times for L1 and L2 cache
are 24 and 40 cycles respectively.If there are 2.5 memory references
per instruction (Assume L2 to memory miss penalty is 250 cycles). 
The average stall cycles per instruction is _______.
```

Here  we have 2.5 memory references per instruction

=> no of instructions = 1000/2.5 = 400 instructions.

Miss Rate of L1 = 250/400

Miss Rate of L2 = 120/400   or    120/250 ?

Should we take denominator for miss rate of L2 to be the total no of instructions

or

total no of instruction 
misses of L1 cache ?

Is the below solution correct ?

[image: Given Solution]

Comment: Is this another practice problem from some site?  Link where you found it, if possible.

Comment: This is an assignment question of a coaching institute. I am not sure if the solution they have given is correct. I have attached the solution along with the question.

Comment: Link where it's from, for 2 reasons: so people can see, and so it's clear what you're quoting (for copyright reasons).

Comment: It is a paid course ; so link is not possible to share; but I have seen that their solutions are incorrect sometimes. Is the above solution correct ?

Comment: You can at least link the front page of wherever it's from.  As far as correctness of this specific case, I don't know, I'm not interested in checking the math and logic on a toy problem.  (Also, real CPUs aren't that simple, especially modern pipelined CPUs that can have multiple cache misses in flight at once.  So knowing formulas like this isn't even useful for tuning real code for modern CPUs.)  Anyway, TL:DR: I'm not interested in the question itself, I'm just trying to get you to improve it so it's not a waste of space on Stack Overflow next to lots of similar cache miss cost-model Q&As

Comment: I'm curious what kind of architecture they have in mind for 2.5 mem refs per instruction though.  2.5 is probably 1 instruction fetch, and a mix of 1 or 2 memory-operand instructions.  So maybe an accumulator architecture, or maybe one which uses memory-indirect addressing.  Anyway, understanding how to turn word problems into math is a useful skill, and in a very broad sense performance scaling with hit-rate is very roughly similar to models like this.  I just mean *I'm* not interested, not that it's a pointless question.

Comment: Should be w.r.t the total number of instructions. Miss in L1 and miss in L2 are mutually exclusive, the terminology is sloppy, "Miss in L1" actually means "Miss in L1 **and** hit in L2". You arrive at the same result (100 cycles) thinking in terms or of cost per memory reference (e.g. 1/4 of those miss in L1, 6/50 miss in L2, so on average a mem access costs 40 cycles). I prefer this approach, but that's just a matter of taste.

Comment: If "L2 cache is hit" only when "L1 cache misses", then total no of references for L2 is no of misses in L1. Miss in  L2 will then cause main memory reference.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is quite compactly written. It would be easier to understand this question if we were to use first principles to arrive at the answer. Cache miss-rate is *number of cache misses / number of cache accesses*; as simple as that. Now, lets look at the question.

Number of instructions = 400. Number of memory references = 1000. (This indeed looks like a made-up problem as Peter mentions in the comments above. In general purpose programs we don't have more memory references than instructions => 2.5x memory accesses / instruction looks artificial)

Anyhow, to complete 400 instructions with all L1 hits we need 1000 x 24 cycles. With the miss schedule given in the question, to complete 400 instructions we need 1000 L1 accesses = 1000 x 24 cycles, 250 L2 accesses = 250 x 40, 120 Main memory accesses = 120 x 250 cycles.

(Average) stall for 400 instructions (compared to the case where all 400 instructions/1000 memory references hit in L1) = 1000x24 +250x40 +120x250 -1000x24 = 250x40 + 120x250.

(Average) stall per instruction is then (250x40 + 120x250) / 400

Comment: Yeah, the formula is not self explanatory; it was difficult to understand the derivation and underlying process applied to arrive at the answer.Thanks for the explanation.